# cwac-loaderex and Proguard

Tags: android, android-sqlite, proguard, commonsware-cwac

I'm using @CommonsWare's [CWAC-LoaderEx](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex) library and its `SQLiteCursorLoader` in my application.

But when I try to use Proguard, I got the following warnings:

```
Warning: com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.SQLCipherCursorLoader: can't find referenced class net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper
Warning: com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.SQLCipherCursorLoader$DeleteTask: can't find referenced class net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase
Warning: com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.SQLCipherCursorLoader$InsertTask: can't find referenced class net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase
Warning: com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.SQLCipherCursorLoader$ReplaceTask: can't find referenced class net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase
Warning: com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.SQLCipherCursorLoader$UpdateTask: can't find referenced class net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase
Warning: com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.SQLCipherUtils: can't find referenced class net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase
Warning: com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.SQLCipherUtils: can't find referenced class net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory
Warning: com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.acl.SQLCipherCursorLoader: can't find referenced class net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase
Warning: com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.acl.SQLCipherCursorLoader$DeleteTask: can't find referenced class net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase
```

... and so on. I have tried adding to my `proguardcfg` file:

```
-libraryjars libs/CWAC-LoaderEx.jar
-keep class net.sqlcipher.** { *; }
-keep class net.sqlcipher.database.** { *; }
```

besides the default `proguard-android.txt`, included in the SDK.

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: This will probably sound like a silly question, but do you have SQLCipher for Android in the project? CWAC-LoaderEx *uses* SQLCipher for Android, and the demo app has a copy of it, but the CWAC-LoaderEx JAR does not include SQLCipher itself.

Comment: That's not a silly question at all, because I don't have SQLCipher in the project! That will, probably, solve the problem, will try right now.

Another question: since I'm not using SQLCipher, can I just tell Proguard to ignore it? Because the app works fine in debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since I'm not using SQLCipher, can I just tell Proguard to ignore it?

You can tell ProGuard to get rid of `com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.SQLCipherCursorLoader`, presumably.

The warnings are just that: warnings. I assumed (incorrectly) that you were crashing in addition to the warnings. So long as you never tried using `SQLCipherCursorLoader`, the warnings would not cause you any particular problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and for the awesome library!

Answer (score 3):

If your application isn't using SQLCipher, you can tell ProGuard to ignore the missing classes. For instance:

```
-dontwarn net.sqlcipher.**
```

See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: can't find referenced class](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass).

You shouldn't specify `-injars` or `-libraryjars` options in your configuration file. The Ant/Eclipse/Gradle build process already automatically specifies all the necessary `-injars`, `-outjars`, and `-libraryjars` for you, based on the contents of your project.

See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Note: duplicate definition of program/library class](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. It should be accepted answer.